# Using case on group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I have a table and wanted to group the row based on the value of session_id. If the session is less than zero than group it by user_id, file_id, and session_id if not then group it by user_id, file_id

The query that I came up with

```
select user_id, file_id, session_id
from memo
group by file_id, user_id, case 
    when session_id < 0 then 'session_id'
end
```

and

```
select user_id, file_id, session_id
from memo
group by case 
    when session_id < 0 then 'file_id, user_id, session_id'
    else 'file_id, user_id'
end
```

The result of both query is

```
user_id     file_id     session_id
8710        1896366041  -1452797155
8710        1896366041  1452797185914
```

What I want is to only have one positive value of session_id while having every unique negative value. My workaround for now is to use 2 queries each using different where statement to handle negative and positive value of session_id. But, it just doesn't feel right because I think using case is the right way

Some sample data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memo` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`content` text NOT NULL,
`last_update` int(11) NOT NULL,
`session_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`object_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`evaluated_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
INSERT INTO `memo` (`id`, `user_id`, `file_id`, `page_id`, `last_update`, `session_id`, `object_id`, `evaluated_id`) VALUES
    (1585, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, -1452797155, '1452797152590_63', 0),
    (1586, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, -1452797155, '1452797153301_61', 0),
    (1588, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, -1452797172, '1452797169976_46', 0),
    (1589, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, -1452797172, '1452797170590_24', 0),
    (1591, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, 1452797185914, '1452797186652_24', 0),
    (1592, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, 1452797185914, '1452797187329_8', 0),
    (1594, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, 1452797200154, '1452797201237_32', 0),
    (1595, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, 1452797200154, '1452797201682_11', 0),
    (1596, 8710, 1896366041, 0, 1452797202, 1452797200154, '1452797201931_93', 0);
```

It would be nice if someone could help me on this, thanks

Comment: that's not going to work. `case` can't return an identifier, it only returns VALUES. that means you're not grouping on the fields `file_id, user_id, etc...`, you're grouping on a fixed/invariant string literal that contains the letters `f`, `i`, `l`, `e, `_`, `i`, `d`, etc...

Comment: You should be using your CASE in the SELECT portion, then group what you find.  That seems like a more sensible way to do it.

Comment: I cant load your sample data in sqlfiddle, please check the sintaxis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers point out, there are other query patterns that will likely get you the result you're after. But I see the track you are on, and it is possible to achieve the specified result using `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY`.

It looks like what you really want is to specify three expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause. (The expressions in the `GROUP BY` cannot be conditionally modified in the execution. It's a static list of expressions.)

The first two expressions are just the column names `file_id` and `user_id`.

It's only third expression you want a conditional test in. If `session_id` is negative, you want to return the value of `session_id`. Otherwise, you want to return a *constant* value, so all of those rows with non-negative values will get grouped together.

Something like this:

```
 GROUP BY file_id
        , user_id
        , CASE WHEN session_id < 0 THEN session_id ELSE NULL END
```

Note that a `CASE` expression returns a *value*. It does not return an *identifier* or a list of identifiers.

Comment: I think this will work. Wish could load the data to test it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that this community could help me this fast. Your answer works like a charm! Thank you so much

Comment: @Pratansyah: +1 (excellent job) on your question. You made it very easy to help you.

Comment: Clean approach in an optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

`case` doean't work like that. You should group both conditions data saparetly and then combine using `UNION`:

```
(select 
    user_id, file_id, session_id
from 
    memo
group by 
    file_id, user_id, session_id
where 
    session_id < 0)

UNION

(select 
    user_id, file_id, session_id
from 
    memo
group by 
    file_id, user_id
where 
    session_id > 0)
```

Comment: Maybe this help even better, create a dummy column `SOURCE` on each union 1 and 2.. Then create one outside query selecting the source you want based in a `CASE`

Comment: It could help if OP's condition was on `SELECT`, but it is on `GROUP BY` actually

Comment: Using `UNION` is in fact my current workaround and it's giving me quite some trouble because the actual query is more complex than this which combine 5 tables. The query that I'm trying to modify is written by someone else and having not so good understanding on SQL I was thinking of grouping it using `CASE` . The problem arise when I tried to order that combined result.

Comment: You could add complete query, may be we could help you out to optimize it. If its not too complex :)

Answer (score 0):

Case is a little overkill for what you want, try this:

```
select user_id, file_id, IF(session_id<0, session_id, 1) AS session_group
from memo
group by file_id, user_id, session_group
```

Also, is there a reason you `group`ing instead of using `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Are you sure we can group a generated column?

Comment: @Shaharyar Yes, as long as the column does not involve an aggregate function, such as SUM, MAX, MIN, etc...